# Limit Wordpress Post Content Based On Category

Tags: wordpress, posts

I want to be able to limit the wordpress post content based on category, eg if i was making a post in politics category i would have a limit of 350 words, if i was making a post in sports category i would have a limit of 450 words.

Comment: Have you tried some custom PHP code that you can share?

Comment: No i have not, am not a wp or php guru.....am looking at the wp codex though..

Comment: This is what i have seen being referenced... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words

Comment: Limit the words in the post. This way it looks nicer without words getting cut off. This does 20 words.

<?php
  $words = explode(" ",strip_tags(get_the_content()));
  $content = implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,20));
  echo $content;
?>